# Control the number of CPU cores sklearn MLPClassifier uses?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cpu-cores

The MLPClassifier in sklearn.neural_network seems to use a lot of available CPU cores, i.e. the python process starts using 50% of processing power when fitting the model. How to prevent this? Is it possible? From the documentation it seem that there is no n_jobs parameter to control this behaviour. I am using sklearn version 0.20 from the November Winpython distribution. This is fine on my notebook but not good on a server others use, too.

Comment: In other classifiers there is the **n_jobs** parameter with which the number of threads is defined

Comment: Yes I know. It seems not to be there for this one. Or did I miss it?

Comment: Google: numpy + BLAS + options. Sklearn is not directly involved

Comment: Ah it is the BLAS in the background doing this? Hm. Let's see.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have tried setting up the number of threads dynamically instead of globally (via an environment variable) but I suggest trying to set the number of threads using `mkl`:

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(3)
```

From personal experience, I noticed that after adding the two lines of code above at the top of my script, my CPU usage would cap around 26~28% (using a desktop with 12 CPUs), even if I were training an `MLPClassifier` which does not have an option to set `n_jobs`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you wrap your MLPClassifier in GridSearchCV? Using GridSearchCV would allow you to set `n_jobs` and optionally you could use ShuffleSplit if you wanted to run GridSearchCV without cross-validation.

For example:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, ShuffleSplit

X,y = make_classification(n_samples=100000)
mlp = MLPClassifier()

grid = GridSearchCV(mlp, {}, n_jobs=1, cv=ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1),
                    verbose=2)
grid.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Yes I thought about such a workaround as well. Did you try it, does it work?

Comment: Hm, I tried the snippet. It claims to use one concurrent worker but actually uses all cores simultaneously.

Comment: Interesting insight. I thought that would work. As a next-step, I would probably look into joblib parallel and see if it's even possible to do this with MLPClassifier. Sorry my answer didn't help.